# runOnUiThread stops Working When Application is Destroyed

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So here's what happening: I'm using the runOnUiThread() method to change an Image View from another class when that class receives a message from another phone. I'm calling it by using mainclass.runOnUiThread(new Runnable...) and so on. It works the first time the application is run, but when I hit the back button to exit the application, and then launch the application again, the Image View no longer updates. The logs I took shows me that everything is fine and being run, but the Image View doesn't change. I don't get any errors and it doesn't crash when I run the application, it just doesn't update the Image View. Any idea what might be causing this?

Edit*: So this is what i'm actually using to change the imageView in a class that doesn't extend Activity

```
peerActivity.runOnUiThread(

                                new Runnable(){

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Log.v("Thread@", "Thread is running");
                                        Log.v("Thread@2", decodedImage.toString());
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        peerActivity.ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);
                                        Log.v("Thread@3", "Past UI Change");

                                    }

                                });
```

Where peerActivity holds the other class reference and ivPHoto is the Image View. What I think I need to do is find a way to kill that thread when the program closes (when I go into the program manager, it still has the Force Close button available). Is there any way to do this?

Edit2*: So I tried a bunch of different approaches to working on the UI Thread and they all give me the same result: The program works perfectly the first time its run but when I hit the back button and close it and the re-open it, the Image View no longer updates. If I force close the app, it works fine again until I close it and re-open it.

Comment: I'm guessing you are decoding an image on a separate thread. Are you using an `AsyncTask`? If not, you should definitely move to that; http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
It will solve your problem as you will return the decoded image to the onPostExecute() method and set it there. The onPostExecute() and onPreExecute() and onProgressUpdate() all run in the UI Thread and should always work.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [View.post(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) instead.

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work. Also tried it with a handler and got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I use new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(...);

You can even create this from a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Runnable is closing over a reference to your activity. When you press back and then start your activity again, your old activity is destroyed and a new instance is created. Your background thread continues to make changes to the original activity, which no longer exists, therefore making changes to its views has no effect.

You need to either stop the updating thread when the actiivty is paused or stopped as appropriate and restart it when the activty is resumed or started (again, as appropriate) and make sure that you are always updating the activty that is actually visible.